# how to import a java class by a jar file

Tags: java

I had a problem when importing org.slf4j.Logger and org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, how to download these two classes and if it is by the mean of a jar file, how to import from it.

Comment: You need to add the jar to your classpath.  Once you do that, you can import classes it contains with a typical import statement.  What IDE are you using? NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

To be able import any classes into your project, such classes should be added to the classpath of your application.

Usually you won't need to extract classes from library, so in your case you need to add slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar from slf4j-1.7.5.zip which accessible here: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Here you can find example how to add library for eclipse project: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Comment: I already did what you said buddy, but it's still does'nt work !!

Comment: I'll try with eclipse like you said

Comment: "does'nt work" - what exactly does this mean? Did you have compilation error, or your code didn't work properly after compile? Also please add your code to question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have the corresponding Jar file, you just have to add it to your project. If you are using Eclipse IDE, you can click on "Project" menu, "Properties", "Java Build Path", "Add External Jars..." and then a file chooser will appear. Choose the location of your Jar file and open it. Here you go. If you are using another IDE, just specify it, so we can further help you with respect to your IDE.